# Arraylist initialization

Tags: java

I have a problem in initializing my `List<List<Integer>>` properly having the famous error out of bounds exception. I know that I can't find the element in my inner list because it doesn't contain ant element in the 0th position. So my question is how to iterate my inner list while adding values properly

```
 public static void main(String[] args) throws FileNotFoundException, IOException {
    // HashMap to stock all my items with keys that i will use for minhashing
    HashMap<String,Integer> hmap= new HashMap<>();
    //Matrice de signatures
    List<List<Integer>> MinHash = new ArrayList<>();

    int numberHashing=6;
    int i=0;
    int nbItems;

    List <Integer> a = new ArrayList<>();
    List <Integer> b = new ArrayList<>();
    //to read my sets that i defined that are the keys
    FileReader in=new FileReader("C:\\items\\items.txt");
    BufferedReader brr = new BufferedReader(in);
    String set ; 

    while( (set = brr.readLine()) != null)
        {   
            StringTokenizer t = new StringTokenizer (set);
            for(int j=0;j<numberHashing;j++)
            {

                MinHash.get(j).add(10000);
            }
            while(t.hasMoreTokens())
            {
                String item=(t.nextToken());
                if(!hmap.containsKey(item))
                {
                    hmap.put(item,i);
                    i++;
                }  
            }
            System.out.println();
        }   
    System.out.println(MinHash);
}
```

The numberHashing will be used for another class that will shuffle my keys afterwards no need to worry about that and the list a and b to contain them. My MinHash is the arrayList I want to initialize at 10000 each. The file i am using for iteration contains 4 lines and 5 words each line. Thank you for helping it may be an easy question that is already answered but any help would be very useful.

Answer (score 0):

You don't create the `numberHashing` elements for `MinHash`, add this initialisation before your `while`:

```
for(int j = 0; j < numberHashing; ++j)
{
    MinHash.add(new ArrayList<Integer>());
}
```